# Nw.js MAC app build damaged

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, nw.js

I have a simple APP, one HTML page, some CSS and one .JS file.

I want to build this app using NW.js, this is my `package.json:`

```
{
    "name": "playlist",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Playlist",
    "main": "index.html",
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "window": {
        "toolbar": false,
        "width": 1200,
        "height": 700,
        "position": "mouse"
    }
}
```

When I run the `nw` command everything runs fine.

I build my app with `nwbuild -p win32,win64 -v 0.12.2  /Users/me/Sites/playlist` but when I open the `build/` directory and try to run my app I recive the following message:

> You can’t open the application “playlist” because it may be damaged or
>   incomplete.

[image]

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to change the security policy on your mac ? 
To resolve this issue, click on the Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Security & Privacy.
On the General tab, click the lock icon in the bottom left to allow for changes. You will be prompted for your password.
Finally, set it to "Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere"

Comment: I keep reciving this You can’t open the application “playlist” because it may be damaged or incomplete.

Comment: Whatever, I've switch to Electron, I strongly recommend.